# Binding a CPen to a list box

Tags: c++, mfc

Does anyone know how to bind a CPen object to a listbox in VS2005 C++?

Can I do it as a ToString with some sort of conversion?

I am creating a custom list of different pens for the user to select.

Thanks.

```
    COLORREF  rgbRED = (255,0,0);
    CPen penRed(PS_SOLID,3,rgbRED);

    CDialog::OnInitDialog();
    ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
    UpdateData();
    lbLineWeight.InsertString(penRed);
```

Comment: I'm assuming that you're talking about MFC, so I've added the tag to your question.

Comment: consider reading `Teach Yourself C++ in 21 Days` it has tutorials for CPen

Comment: I would avoid reading anything titled "Teach Yourself _insert something complex_ in _xx_ Hours/Days" as that's going to be an unrealistic summary of highlights at best.

Comment: Oh, "C-pen". I thought it was like "CP-en", I had to google it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 options.

- (simple) Use a normal CListBox with strings as the items, and keep the link between the string to the actual CPen as free functions (or member of some other classes) and you will have to do a one-to-one association between the current selected item (usually an index number) and the CPen information you have.
- (a bit more complex) Derive your own class from CListBox and keep the CPen data internally, you will still have to keep a list of valid CPen in that new class, and do the one-to-one association between the selected item and the actual CPen; as a bonus you can make you derived CListBox owner-drawn and instead of using string, you could draw some sort of representation of each pen in the list items.

Another tought, you could add the CPen as a user data to each CListBox item (CListBox::SetItemData) to make the link between the item and the actual item a bit more easy.

Good luck.

Max.

Comment: Combine my idea with bullet point #2 here could look nifty you could add a icon or bitmap member to the the helper struct and use that in a `CImageList` to put a little icon next to the name in the list box. The possibilities are quite endless when it comes to GUI.

Comment: Is there a simpler way like something along these lines: 
COLORREF  rgbRED = (255,0,0);
 CPen penRed(PS_SOLID,3,rgbRED);

 CDialog::OnInitDialog();
 ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
 UpdateData();
 lbLineWeight.InsertString(penRed);

Comment: Can you point me to an example that shows how to add it to a list box using the simple method? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I understand you correctly you want to have a `CListBox` which allows the user to select a `CPen` for use elsewhere.

I would probably make a little helper class:

```
struct PenHelper
{
   CString m_displayName;
   LOGPEN m_penProps;

   bool CreatePen(CPen* pPen)
   {
       return pPen->CreatePenIndirect(&m_penProps) == 1;
   }
};
```

The idea being you could have a container like `std::map` of multiple `PenHelper` each with a names like "Solid Red" and a corresponding `LOGPEN` struct with properties that match the name. In the `CListBox` you add the display name string. When they select one you can look it up by name and use the create function to actually make the corresponding `CPen`

Just one of a million ways to skin a cat.

**Edit:** Quick note. In order to handle `ON_LBN_SELCHANGE` in your message map for when they make a selection in your `CListBox` make sure you gave it the `LBS_NOTIFY` style in the `Create` call otherwise it won't fire.